# Python - Creating JSON array? and passing to ajax

Tags: python, arrays, json, ajax, parsing

in my python server-side script i have the following

```
....


data = {}
data['id'] = id
data['organizer'] = organizer
data['eventStart'] = eventStartLocal
data['eventEnd'] = eventEndLocal
data['subject'] = subject
data['attendees'] = attendees
# Serializing Data 
json_data = json.dumps(data)
id += 1
print(json_data) #this is what the script returns
```

In my front-end using jquery/javascript i have this..

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'REQUEST',
       dataType: 'text',
          url: 'json.py',
          success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
               obj = JSON.parse(data);
               },

            }).done(function(){

                console.log(obj)
            })

        });
```

my output is:

```
{"id": 0, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"}
{"id": 1, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"}
{"id": 2, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"}
```

**My issue**

When i try to parse the json in javascript, i get an error code about

> Unexpected token { in JSON at position

After doing some research, i found that i would have to send a json array as a response and not print a jsoned line for each event, otherwise my javascript wont be able to parse it and put it in an object.

**My Goal**

To get data from server and pass it to javascript as an object so that i can loop through that object and create an HTML element for each event.

I'm new to this JSON stuff, somehow i need to do the following, but i don't seem to know how to create a json array (that has the [ ] and the , at the end of each json/line.

```
[
    {"id": 0, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"},
    {"id": 1, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"},
    {"id": 2, "organizer": "Some Name", "eventStart": "09:30 AM", "eventEnd": "10:00 AM", "subject": "rental procedure", "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"}
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

... the JSON array at the end of your answer is incorrect, but to generate an array, just give a list to json.dumps in Python. Something like `json_data_list = []; ... ; json_data_list.append(json_data); ... print(json.dumps(json_data_list)); ...`

Comment: ahh i see that's the part that i was missing.. So the solution was to create a list and append my data to the list `data_list.append(data)` and then jsonify `data_list`. =) thank you!

Comment: @user234461 You saved my day ==> `print(json.dumps(json_data_list));` that spells out to get the final appended list as json data. Thank you so much

Comment: @jAntoni That's great to hear, thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON file is incorrect. Normally you must have a structure as:

```
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "name": "Toto"
        },
        {
            "id": "blibli",
            "name": "Tata"
        }
    ],
    "key2": {
        "id": "value"
    },
    "key3": "value"
}
```

So I think you have to change your JSON array for example as following:

```
{
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can decide also to have not a list of dictionary as I proposed above but to use the ID value as key for each dictionary; in that case you have:

```
{
    "id0":{       
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
    },
    "id1":{       
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
    },
    "id2":{       
            "organizer": "Some Name",
            "eventStart": "09:30 AM",
            "eventEnd": "10:00 AM",
            "subject": "rental procedure",
            "attendees": "Some Name<br />Person 2<br />Person 3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second JSON block is an object containing a list, but the list does not have a name. I believe bare lists are allowed in JSON (i.e. with no enclosing object), but if not, you need to give the list a name.